# Keep 'distant' Fragments updated and ready for users in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a couple of `Fragment`s with `RecyclerView`s in a `ViewPager`. On actions in the first `Fragment`, the remaining `Fragment`s change what they display.

I can access all the `Fragment`s from the first one and call update methods on them. The problem is, the updates do not happen if I do not swipe to the other `Fragment`s. In fact, before tapping any action buttons in the first `Fragment`, I have to swipe to the other `Fragment`s (without purpose) just to keep the app from crashing with a `NullPointerException`.

The reason I guess is because the remaining `Fragment`s are `null` as they are not brought into view.

I have tried this approach so far, in vain:

```
public void updatePager(int pagePosition)
{
    ((NMMain) getActivity()).dsFragment.updateDSFragment(dView);

    nMParentViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gsSupremePager);
    nMParentViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    nMParentViewPager.setCurrentItem(pagePosition, true);
} // of updatePager()
```

**`Log`**

After clicking action buttons in Fragment1 ***after swiping to fragments***:

`02-06 14:53:21.563 7765-8678/com.my A/NMDBHelper class: Create View-1 query: CREATE VIEW View_Temp 02-06 14:53:21.585 7765-8678/com.my A/NMDBHelper class: Create dealsView-2 query: CREATE TABLE D_View 02-06 14:53:21.748 7765-7765/com.my 
E/DSFragment: In frag2.updateFragment(): dView.size() = 3`

After clicking action buttons in Fragment1 ***without swiping to any fragments***:

`02-06 14:58:52.691 11967-11967/com.nearme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.my, PID: 11967 java.lang.NullPointerException at com.my.s.Frag2.updatePager(Frag2.java:xxx)`

So my question,

- Irrespective of the visibility of a `Fragment` in a `ViewPager`, how can they (`Fragment`s) be kept ready with the latest content?

Comment: Doesn't `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` manage Fragment references okay?

Comment: @cricket_007, my pager adapter extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`,Is there something 'else' that must be done in the adapter, to meet my requirement?

Comment: Maybe. Hard to tell in the code you are showing, but somewhere you are losing the references to the "pages" in the ViewPager, which causes them to be null. I have a project that I used an ArrayList of Fragments for the Adapter (kinda like a custom ArrayAdapter for Fragments) that seemed to work out okay

Comment: I do not use any collection for fragments. Surely, the fragments cannot be null, because if I swipe to them (pointlessly), come back to Fragment 1 and do an action which runs a method in the fragment I just swiped to, there's no `NPE`. If I don't swipe to that fragment and do the action, there is an `NPE` that crashes the app.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you should add the logcat and relevant code to your question instead of me just guessing what the solution should be

Comment: Please use the edit link under your question to add that information rather than using the comments

Comment: Sorry about the messy comment. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was thinking and the way I worded the question - oh so complex.

All I was looking to do was ***pre-load*** fragment pages. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341779/preload-fragments-view-in-viewpager-on-first-run) resolved it. So, [`ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) is the answer.

Though this is not *my answer*, hope it will help someone who bumps into similar complexity and lands here.

Thanks for looking in, @cricket_007 and all the others.