# Multiple calls to getView GridView in ViewPager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, android-viewpager

I have `ViewPager` of fragments and every fragment contains `GridView`. The issue I am facing is `ViewPager` calls `getView` of GridView adapter many times. I want to change `GridView` item views but multiple calls is creating issue in logic. Is there any way to block multiple calls or Is there any event that `FragmentPagerAdapter` has created all fragments, then I send broadcast to all fragments to view changes?

**UPDATE**

```
if(AppPreferences.getString(AppPreferenceKeys.EDIT_INVOICE_NUMBER, "").length() > 0) {
                int quantity = ((MainActivity) context).getQuantity(menu.getMenuCode() + "");
                if (quantity > 0) {
                    holder.cv_menu.findViewById(R.id.rl_cv_menu).setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.accepted));
                    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
//                        holder.cv_menu.performClick();
                        handleMenuItemClick(holder.cv_menu);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If "multiple calls is creating issue in logic", then you're not implementing your `Adapter` correctly.

Comment: @PiyushGupta: Please see the updated post. I want to change the background color of gridview item. but only last item is updated.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341779/preload-fragments-view-in-viewpager-on-first-run